# HP Flex 5510 switch configuration back up issue

Tags: hp, hp-comware

I'm new to HP switch's,
I'm struggling to take a configuration backup file from a HP 5510 flex switch (Comware series).
I've tried all possible methods to pull out the config file via both CLI and GUI, but couldn't get it.

Please suggest any possible way to pull the config file for future restoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable SFTP:

```
system-view
sftp server enable
```

Then use SFTP to download *startup.cfg* from the switch.

Comment: SFTP already enabled,